# For loop with generic parameters in Java

Tags: java, generics, parameters

Short question - how should it look like to work?

```
private <T> boolean hasElement(T array, T element) {
    for (T el : array) {
        if (el.equals(element)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now it shows error in line where for loop starts.

Comment: _Now it shows error in line where for loop starts._ what error?

Comment: _for-each not applicable to expression type_ (I use Netbeans)

Comment: @GangamStyle you suggest `<T extends Iterable<T>>`. May a see a practical implementation of this type?

Answer (score 12):

```
private <T> boolean hasElement(T[] array, T element) {
                                ^^
```

Comment: Note that `boolean hasElement(Object[] array, Object element)` will work for _exactly_ the same inputs, because if you try passing `hasElement(String[], Integer)` to this version, it'll just automatically upcast them to `Object[], Object`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman not true. `String[]` can't be upcasted to `Object[]`

Comment: @LouisWasserman strange... what was the last version where it didn't work?

Comment: I _think_ `String[]` has been upcastable to `Object[]` since 1.0.  (Mind you, I frequently wish you were right and it didn't work this way...)

Comment: @JanDvorak: It has always been this way with arrays. Perhaps you are confusing array component types with type parameters of generic types?

Comment: @LouisWasserman the corresponding runtime exception _does_ exist since 1.0

Comment: @JanDvorak What, do you mean `ArrayStoreException`?  Yes, that's what happens when you actually try to put an `Integer` into a `String[]` that's been upcast to an `Object[]`, but it doesn't stop you from doing the upcast.  That's how it is now, and always has been.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
private <T> boolean hasElement(T[] array, T element) {
    for (T el : array) {
        if (el.equals(element)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

not that though generic version is better still this version will compile and work too

```
private boolean hasElement(Object[] array, Object element) {
    for (Object el : array) {
        if (el.equals(element)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The second version will not accept `myClass[]` as the first argument.

Comment: "though generic version is better" I disagree. Generics should only be used where it has an effect on type safety. In this case it accepts the same inputs, so the generics is completely meaningless.